# R - calculate the mean of values separated by NAs in a dataframe

Tags: row, mean, na, group

I feel this should be very easy, but I cannot find a solution. I am using Rstudio (R version 4.2.1) on Windows 10.

I have a data frame df that contains a column where cells contain either numeric values or NAs. Some values are given in blocks, or values stand alone, separated by NAs.

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(NA, NA, 4, 7, 1, NA, NA, 12, NA, 14, 7, NA))
```

| value |
| --- |
| NA |
| NA |
| 4 |
| 7 |
| 1 |
| NA |
| NA |
| 12 |
| NA |
| 14 |
| 7 |
| NA |

My question is, how can I calculate the mean of those values in blocks between NAs, and save the results in a new column? The mean of the values in blocks should be repeated in the new column, and the standalone values should simply be retained in the new column?

So that I get something like this:

| value | newcolumnmean |
| --- | --- |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| 4 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| NA | NA |
| NA | NA |
| 12 | 12 |
| NA | NA |
| 14 | 10.5 |
| 7 | 10.5 |
| NA | NA |

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using tidyverse/dplyr to filter all values without NA, and then tried using lag to shift through the rows in the column, but to no avail.